# ServiceStack - how to host multiple versioned endpoints in one service?

Tags: c#, .net, wsdl, messaging, servicestack

## Where I was

I'm trying to convert some WCF services to use ServiceStack instead. For the most part it's achieving what I want but there's definitely differences. eg with WCF I had something like:

```
interface IMethod1{ ResultDTO Method1(InputDTO input); }
interface IMethod2{ ResultDTO Method2(InputDTO input); }
interface IMethod3{ ResultDTO Method3(InputDTO input); }

interface IMyService : IMethod1, IMethod2, IMethod3
```

then implement with:

```
public class MyService : ServiceBase, IMyService { /*  ... */ }
```

---

## Where I'm at

With ServiceStack it's more like:

```
public class Method1{
    // parameters for method as properties
}
public class Method2{
    // parameters for method as properties
}
public class Method3{
    // parameters for method as properties
}
```

I've tried various thing and the latest dead-end I've hit was with:

```
public class MyServiceHost<T> : AppHostBase
{
    public MyServiceHost(string version)
        : base("My Service v" + version, typeof(T).Assembly)
    { }

    public override void Configure(Funq.Container container){
        Routes.AddFromAssembly(typeof(T).Assembly);  
    }
}

protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    new MyServiceHost<Foo.Bar.V0101.MyService>("1.1").Init();
    new MyServiceHost<Foo.Bar.V0102.MyService>("1.2").Init();            
    new MyServiceHost<Foo.Bar.V0201.MyService>("2.1").Init();            
}
```

where it complains that AppHost has already been initialised.

---

## Where I want to be

I want to expose something like this:

```
http://www.sandwich.com/example/v0101/sandwichservice.wsdl
http://www.sandwich.com/example/v0102/sandwichservice.wsdl
http://www.sandwich.com/example/v0201/sandwichservice.wsdl
```

or

```
http://www.sandwich.com/example/sandwich_v0101.wsdl
http://www.sandwich.com/example/sandwich_v0102.wsdl
http://www.sandwich.com/example/sandwich_v0201.wsdl
```

ideally hosted in the same service process.

So is there a simple answer I'm missing or am I approaching the whole thing fundamentally wrong? Or in a nutshell: using ServiceStack, is it possible to and how can I expose multiple endpoints and WSDLs for versioned web services in the same host service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this answer for [recommended versioning strategies with ServiceStack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12413091/85785).

You can't expose multiple versions of SOAP/WSDL's in ServiceStack, you're encouraged to evolve the same DTO's which means there are no previous type versions to create an older version of the WSDL. You would need to host older versions of ServiceStack project for the auto-generated WSDL to match up with older types.

You could also take a snapshot of a WSDL and host it statically, but whether a new SOAP endpoint accepts a client sending an old SOAP version is up to .NET's WCF Message class doing the parsing. But as SOAP is a brittle format, YMMV.

Comment: OK maybe try from a different angle. Instead of two versions of one WSDL, can you host multiple services with distinct WSDLs doing the above? eg have one WSDL for GetContact AddContact etc and another for PlaceOrder CancelOrder etc?

Comment: It's not a feature that exists atm, but you can [suggest the new feature here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/issues/new) (if you do, state your use-case). At the moment you would need to split types into separate dlls and reference them in stub host projects for the purposes of WSDL generation. Then you can have your **real** project referencing all dll types in the AppHostBase constructor.