# ServiceStack AppHost Is a Singleton?

Tags: c#, servicestack

I have been evaluating ServiceStack and so far, I've been pretty much sold - but I have a requirement that I *think* is going to be a deal-breaker.

I basically need multiple AppHost-derived instances.  The first one spins up nicely, but the rest fail because "AppHostBase.Instance has already been set".

Does this mean if I want multiple hosts (on different Uris), to be in different executables?  If so this is rather disappointing as this library is perfect in every single other way, other than this limitation.

If I am wrong, can anyone point me to a solution?

Allow me to elaborate a little.  We have plans for many, many services across the network.  My intention is that they are designed as individual services and then "hosted" in a hosting class.  The hosting class itself is a service for administrative purposes and has the ability to start and stop services.  They are "discoverable" across the network.  We can spin up and spin down services on different machines at different times, or at will.

My plan was to use service-stack for each of these things and have the ability to create and destroy the services in an ad-hoc manner on any machine and in any "host".  The only thing I am stumbling on is the AppHost only being initialised once.

Obviously I am doing something wrong, so any information on how to host multiple services in the same executable would be great :)

Comment: So you want multiple services on different port numbers from the same process? Using the Route attribute with Servicestack I have four endpoints on my software: http://+:12000/route1, http://+:12000/route2, etc.

Comment: @Brannon, the individual services can disappear and reappear at any time.  Not sure if that will help.  They are also on their *own* URI for this reason and can disappear at one point of the network and appear on the other.  A directory service is used to discover where things are.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In response to this question I've added new [Modularizing services](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Modularizing-services) and [Physical project structure](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Physical-project-structure) wiki pages to highlight the different ways of structuring and modularizing ServiceStack services which I'll repeat hear for discoverability:

As you've discovered, ServiceStack has a **single App Host** for each App Domain. As you might be able to infer from the name, the role of the **Host** project is to be the conduit for binding all your services concrete dependencies, plugins, filters and everything else your service needs. The configuration of your service should be immutable after everything is initialized in your `AppHost.Configure()` method. The [Physical project structure wiki page](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Physical-project-structure) wiki shows the recommended physical project structure for typical solutions.

#### Modularizing services in multiple assemblies

Whilst you can only have 1 AppHost, services can be spread across multiple assemblies by providing the Assemblies in the AppHostBase constructor, e.g:

```
public class AppHost : AppHostBase
{
    //Tell Service Stack the name of your application and which assemblies to find your web services
    public AppHost() : base("Hello ServiceStack!", 
       typeof(ServicesFromDll1).Assembly, ServicesFromDll2).Assembly /*, etc */) { }

    public override void Configure(Container container) {}
}
```

You can also provide your own strategy for discovering and resolving the service types that ServiceStack should auto-wire by overriding `CreateServiceManager`, e.g:

```
public class AppHost : AppHostBase
{
    public AppHost() : base("Hello ServiceStack!", typeof(ServicesFromDll1).Assembly) { }
    public override void Configure(Container container) {}

    //Provide Alternative way to inject IOC Container + Service Resolver strategy
    protected virtual ServiceManager CreateServiceManager(params Assembly[] assembliesWithServices)
    {       
        return new ServiceManager(new Container(),
            new ServiceController(() => assembliesWithServices.ToList().SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())));
    }
}
```

#### Encapsulating Services inside Plugins

One way of modularizing services is to encapsulate them inside [Plugins](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Plugins) which allows you to manually register services, custom routes, filters, content types, allow customization and anything else your module needs.

To illustrate this point, we'll show what a Basic [Auth Feature](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/AuthFeature.cs) example might look like:

```
public class BasicAuthFeature : IPlugin 
{
    public string HtmlRedirect { get; set; }   //User-defined configuration

    public void Register(IAppHost appHost)
    {
        //Register Services exposed by this module
        appHost.RegisterService<AuthService>("/auth", "/auth/{provider}");
        appHost.RegisterService<AssignRolesService>("/assignroles");
        appHost.RegisterService<UnAssignRolesService>("/unassignroles");

        //Load dependent plugins
        appHost.LoadPlugin(new SessionFeature());
    }
}
```

With everything encapsulated inside a plugin, your users can easily enable them in your AppHost with:

```
Plugins.Add(new BasicAuthFeature { HtmlRedirect = "~/login" });
```

### [Physical Project Structure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15235822/85785)

See this [earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15235822/85785) on the recommended way to physically layout your project.

Comment: Thanks very much for your prompt response.  I am having trouble visualising what the class is for the services in the other assemblies.  Obviously they do not derive from AppHost.  Also I assume therefore that there is a single Uri for all of the services, but the routes are determined based on the types passed through?  I think this might well be a perfect solution.  Also, can I register those assemblies at a later date or do they *have* to be done at construction time?  I can work around it if not.

Comment: Single URI for all services? You specify what the `/root` of where ServiceStack will be mounted at and then all services are from that root, but they can have any custom url structure. Yes assemblies must be specified on construction (construction happens anywhere in App_Start) whilst all other configuration within `AppHost.Configure()`. You can manually register services using `appHost.RegisterService<T>("/path")` shown above.

Comment: Thanks very much for this response.  For some reason I am still having trouble envisaging how one of my services "comes online" and then can come "offline", or effectively unregister.  Providing the assemblies to the AppHost on construction is actually not an issue, as the config file is processed at startup and I know all assemblies that may provide services ahead of time.  Just trying to see how this works.  Many thanks, and keep up the great work providing the community with such an amazing, self-sufficient, light weight and high-performance solution :)