# Service Stack and multiple instances of the same service on a single server

Tags: servicestack

I have a Service Stack deployment question. On our production server we have a UAT site and a live site. Each site has its own URL. The service is to be deployed to the site as an application an accessed via a URL such as UAT.example.org/service for UAT and example.org/service for live.

Is this possible or will the 2 instances of the service conflict?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17888996/two-service-stack-apis-on-the-same-iis-server/17898593 It works the same as any ASP.net application.

Comment: Thank you kampsj. That is exactly what I have been looking for. If you add your comment as an answer I will accept it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple ServiceStack implementations will work the same as any other ASP.NET application.

See [Two service stack APIs on the same IIS server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17898593/215502)