# ServiceStack Database first example

Tags: servicestack

I would like to start new project using Servicestack with existing database (SQL Server) .I really like and also learning from pluralsight servicstack tutorial .I would like to request some help as currently facing some challenges as i am new ,  I am looking for example/tutorial to get me start with POCO with existing table mapping . very basic example with one table and one service request will enough for me to get started .

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

First to get an overview of OrmLite features I  recommend reading the docs on **[OrmLite's Homepage](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/)**.

To get started with OrmLite in ServiceStack first install the preferred OrmLite provider from NuGet, e.g to use an InMemory database just install Sqlite from NuGet:

```
Install-Package ServiceStack.OrmLite.Sqlite.Mono
```

** **OrmLite.Sqlite.Mono** supports both Windows and Mono, for a Windows only x86/x64 Sqlite you can use [OrmLite.Sqlite.Windows](http://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.OrmLite.Sqlite.Windows). For SQL Server install [OrmLite.SqlServer](http://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer) instead.*

Then to use OrmLite in ServiceStack you just need to register a DB Connection Factory with the RDBMS provider and connection string you want to use:

```
public void Configure(Container container)
{
    container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(c => 
        new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(":memory:", SqliteDialect.Provider));
}
```

By default OrmLite supports POCO's that map **1:1** to RDBMS tables, so a simple class like:

```
public class Simple
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? Age { get; set; }
}
```

Can be created with:

```
using (var db = container.Resolve<IDbConnectionFactory>().Open())
{
    //Drops (if exists) and re-creates SimpleTable
    db.DropAndCreateTable<Simple>();  
}
```

Which will create an RDBMS table with the following definition:

```
CREATE TABLE "Simple" 
(
  "Id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
  "Name" VARCHAR(8000) NULL, 
  "Age" INTEGER NULL 
);
```

You can further use attributes to customize how the table is created, e.g:

```
[Alias("CustomTable")]
public class Simple
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Alias("CustomAge")]
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Which will generate the following SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE "CustomTable" 
(
  "Id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
  "Name" VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
  "CustomAge" INTEGER NOT NULL 
);
```

OrmLite also continues to use the custom Aliases in future API's.

In ServiceStack you can access OrmLite from the ADO.NET `Db` connection in the `Service` base class. As OrmLite tables are just POCO's you can if you wish re-use them as Request DTO's (although it's [recommended to have purpose-specific Request DTO's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15235822/85785)).

E.g. this ServiceStack Service below returns a single `Simple` row if `Id` is provided, otherwise returns all `Simple` entries:

```
public class MyServices : Service
{
    public object Any(Simple request)
    {
        return request.Id != default(int)
            ? Db.SingleById<Simple>(request.Id)
            : Db.Select<Simple>();
    }
}
```

Most of [ServiceStack example projects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15869816/85785) utilize OrmLite, to get started I recommend going through these well documented examples first:

- [Email Contacts](https://github.com/ServiceStack/EmailContacts/)
- [Http Benchmarks](https://github.com/ServiceStack/HttpBenchmarks)

Comment: Hi , Thank for you reply .I already tested and it is working however I want to work on existing database, currently running windows application with existing data , can you please show me how can i use database first approach to map existing data table to POCOs. One example for generate and map sample table to POCOs will be very helpful . Thanks again .

Comment: @Zayar You would need to create POCO classes that map to your Tables, you can use [OrmLite's T4 templates](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/#t4-template-support) to initially help with generating the classes.

Comment: great i will try and let you know .

Comment: Nice, didn't know ormlite.mono supported both windows and mono. +1 for that

Answer (score 2):

Please, look at this question [In what order are the ServiceStack examples supposed to be grokked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15862634/in-what-order-are-the-servicestack-examples-supposed-to-be-grokked/15869816#15869816)

To be more specific, you can probably start from https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples/tree/master/src/ServiceStack.Northwind

Comment: Northwind example gives me a bunch of errors when I open in Visual Studio