# Migrating to ServiceStack's new API from MVC4 Web API

Tags: servicestack

What is the best way of organizing files/code in ServiceStack new API. I worked on MVC 4 Web API where we organize files in App_start folder(routes, webapiconfig, filters), Controllers (all apiControllers)?

Also I with Controllers folder I have 2 files pc.cs and mobile.cs. pc.cs has all api related to pc where service can be accessed via xyz.com/api/pc/GetUsers and mobile.cs has all api related to mobile where service can be accessed via xyz.com/api/mobile/GetMinutes.

using appHost

```
setConfig(new EndpointHostConfig {ServiceStackHandlerFactoryPath = "api"});
```

I could achieve api in the uri.

Can this be replicated in ServiceStack? If yes how? and on the other hand, what is the suggested (best practice) in terms of organizing such services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the recommended [Physical Project Structure wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Physical-project-structure) for an example which shows how we'd go about physically laying out the projects for this [Simple REST API design example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15231537/recommended-servicestack-api-structure/15235822#15235822).

If your looking at maintaining a very large number of services look at the [Modularizing services wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Modularizing-services) which shows how you can split services across multiple dlls and encapsulate them in [Plugins](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Plugins).

Comment: The physical project structure wiki is a bit confusing (cannot co-relate to Web API). I saw that before adding this question.

Comment: I think it's pretty straight forward so I don't know what to tell you, maybe stop thinking in MVC + WebApi Controllers? ServiceStack services are pretty clean, simple pure C# autowired services accepting and returning clean DTOs.