# ServiceStack Application Structure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, servicestack

I have recently started looking at `ServiceStack` and how we could implement it in our architecture. We have been using ASP.NET MVC 3/4 with the Service/Repository/UnitOfWork pattern.

I am looking for resources of how to integrate ServiceStack into the mix.

What we usually have looks something like this:

`MVC Controller/Action` --> `Service` --> `Repository` --> `Entity Framework`

I want to re-use the domain model we have and expose it through ServiceStack, so do I just have the operation's on the services return the domain models?

E.G.

```
// Request DTO
public class Customer
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
}

// Response DTO
public class CustomerResponse
{
    public List<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}

// Customer Service
public class CustomerService : IService
{
    public object Any(BrowseCustomers request)
    {
        var customers = new List<Customer>() {
            new Customer {
                FirstName = "Joe",
                LastName = "Bob",
                ...
            },
            new Customer {
                FirstName = "Jill",
                LastName = "Bob",
                ...
            }
        };

        return customers.Where(x => x.FirstName.ToLower().StartsWith(request.FirstName.ToLower()));
    }
}
```

**Edit**

I guess what I am asking is; Should I return Domain Objects in the Response DTO's from the ServiceStack Services? Or should I not return domain objects at all, rather make entity DTO's instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a fairly comprehensive write-up on Service Stack application architecture, see Demis' answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15235822/85785).

Long story short, as long as your Domain objects are POCOs (Plain Old CLR Objects - meaning no methods or inheritance going on), then you should be fine.

The important point is that your Request/Response DTOs are logical for the operations you want to expose with your services. Don't use a Domain model for a Request DTO because it's convenient, do it because it's the best choice. Having your Response DTOs contain Domain models is quite common, though.