# ServiceStack C# strongly typed client DTO

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, rest, servicestack

Here: [Recommended ServiceStack API Structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15231537/recommended-servicestack-api-structure) and here: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Physical-project-structure are recommendations for how to structure your projects for C# clients to reuse DTOs.

Apparently this is done by including a dll of the DTO assembly.  I have searched the web for one example, just Hello World that uses a separate assembly DTO for a C# client in ServiceStack.  Perhaps I should be able to break this out myself but so far it has not proven that easy.

Almost all client descriptions are for generic and non-typed JSON or other non-DTO based clients.  No one appears interested in typed C# clients like I am (even the ServiceStack documentation I have found).  So I thought this would be a good question even if I figure it out myself in the end.

To be clear, I have built and run the Hello World example server.  I have also used a browser to attach to the server and interact with it.  I have also created a client empty project that can call

`JsonServiceClient client = new JsonServiceClient(myURL);`

Then I tried to copy over my DTO definition without the assembly DLL as I don't have one.  I get `ResponseStatus` is undefined.

Clearly there is something missing (it appears to be defined in `ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll`) and if I could create a dll of the DTO I think it would resolve all references.

Can anyone give insight into how to create the DTO assembly for the simple Hello World?

Edited to add code:

```
using ServiceStack.ServiceClient.Web;
namespace TestServiceStack
{
  class HelloClient
  {     public class HelloResponse
    {
      public string Result { get; set; }
      public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; } //Where Exceptions get auto-serialized
    }

    //Request DTO
    public class Hello
    {
      public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    HelloResponse response = client.Get(new Hello { Name = "World!" });
  }
}
```

Where the ResponceStatus is undefined.

Comment: It would be much clearer if you post some code. At the moment it seems that your problem lies elsewhere since including a Dtos library works exactly the same as including any other dll.

Comment: I did not post code because the code is all in the public source domain of <http://mono.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Hello/>.  If I follow that tutorial I can build the Hello application which I did for Host.Asp.Net.  That was the server.  The client I tried to copy the DTO code over:

Comment: @JoannaTurban I hope the code I added was what you were referring to.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the missing symbol ResponseStatus by adding:

```
using ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.ServiceModel;
```

Here is the full code that built.  Keep in mind that I found out something else in the process.  Once this built it then failed because I was using a DTO from a .NET 4.0 environment in a .NET 3.5 environment.  But that is an unrelated issue.  Also note that this test code does nothing with the response, it is just an example to get the build working.

```
using ServiceStack.ServiceClient;
using ServiceStack.ServiceInterface;
using ServiceStack.Text;
using ServiceStack.Service;
using ServiceStack.ServiceHost;
using ServiceStack.WebHost;
using ServiceStack;
using ServiceStack.ServiceClient.Web;
using RestTestRoot;  // This is the name of my DTO assembly.  You will need to insert your own here.
using ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.ServiceModel;

namespace WebApplicationRoot
{

    class HelloClient
    {
        JsonServiceClient hello_client;

        //Request DTO
        public class Hello
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }

        //Response DTO
        public class HelloResponse
        {
            public string Result { get; set; }
            public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; } //Where Exceptions get auto-serialized
        }
        //Can be called via any endpoint or format, see: http://mono.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Hello/
        public class HelloService : Service
        {
            public object Any(Hello request)
            {
                return new HelloResponse { Result = "Hello, " + request.Name };
            }
        }

        //REST Resource DTO
        [Route("/todos")]
        [Route("/todos/{Ids}")]
        public class Todos : IReturn<List<Todo>>
        {
            public long[] Ids { get; set; }
            public Todos(params long[] ids)
            {
                this.Ids = ids;
            }
        }

        [Route("/todos", "POST")]
        [Route("/todos/{Id}", "PUT")]
        public class Todo : IReturn<Todo>
        {
            public long Id { get; set; }
            public string Content { get; set; }
            public int Order { get; set; }
            public bool Done { get; set; }
        }


        public HelloClient(){
        //        ServiceStack gateway = new ServiceStack.ClientGateway(
        //               location.protocol + "//" + location.host + '/ServiceStack.Examples.Host.Web/ServiceStack/');
            hello_client = new JsonServiceClient("http://tradetree2.dnsapi.info:8080/");
            hello_client.Get<HelloResponse>("/hello/MyTestWorld!");
        }
    }
}
```