# How do I secure the ServiceStack license key on a mobile client?

Tags: servicestack, license-key, servicestack-text

I've just bought a ServiceStack.Text license and I want to incorporate it into my code. On the server-side, I can do this securely. However I need this to also work on a mobile client device, as I need to serialize/deserialize things on the mobile device. I can't seem to find/figure out a secure way of handling this. As far as I can tell, it will always be readable in the mobile client's memory.

Am I mistaken in this? Is there some other way of handling this, perhaps somehow using the Service Clients mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23006539/servicestack-client-text-licensing)? (But I need to do the serializing/deserializing on the client itself, not just posting to a server.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a good idea to use some [Simple string obfuscation techniques](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13025949/85785) so the license key is not visible in plain-text when analyzing your decompiled program and so will require some effort to decipher, but ultimately it's [impossible to secure protected keys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6018247/85785) inside your deployed application given by design if your application needs and can read it, it will always be decryptable with enough effort.

Comment: Thanks for the extremely quick reply! I just wanted to make sure I was doing due diligence for protection of the key, as I did not know if you had a mechanism in your library that I couldn't find that avoided resorting to obfuscation. I'm just glad your library doesn't have the PCL problems I've had with other Json serializers!