# ServiceStack Message via RabbitMq routing to verb other than POST

Tags: servicestack, rabbitmq

implementing service bus with servicestack and rabbitmq here.

Documentation states "each message will instead be executed by the best matching ServiceStack Service that handles the message with either a Post or Any fallback verb".

How then would I make the published message from the client route to PUT?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions or samples.

Answer (score 0):

> each message will instead be executed by the best matching ServiceStack Service that handles the message with either a Post or Any fallback verb"

This documentation says that messages are treated as `POST` requests, as such can only be handled with `Post(Request)` or `Any(Request)` handlers. This is the same as ServiceStack's SOAP Support where all SOAP request are `POST`'s, which you can ensure is accessible by SOAP/MQ requests by [maintaining separate Request DTO's](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/SOAP-support#soap--rest) ([a common and recommended practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15235822/85785)) and implementing them using `Any()` so they're still accessible by both `PUT` and `POST` requests, e.g:

```
[Route("/customers", "POST"]
public class CreateCustomer { ... }

[Route("/customers/{Id}", "PUT"]
public class UpdateCustomer { ... }

public class CustomerService : Service
{
    public object Any(CreateCustomer request) { ... }
    public object Any(UpdateCustomer request) { ... }
}
```

This service enables access to the service via `POST /customers` and `PUT /customers/1` HTTP routes while still allowing them to be accessed via SOAP/MQ.

Comment: Thank you for this information. revising implementation.