# How Data is posted (POST) to Service in Servicestack , is it through URL?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, servicestack

I have complex requstDto which composed of other list of DTO's (Entity framework Entities)  like

```
[Route("/demoservice/{Userdemo}/{EmployerDemoid}/{ReportDemo}/{DemoselectedDataList}/", "POST")]
        public class ReportDemo : IReturn<String>
        {
           
            public List<selectedidList> selectedDataList{ get; set; }            
            
        }
```

where UserReport  is follows

```
public class UserReport  
        {
            public string UserName { get; set; }
            public Datetime CreatedON{ get; set; }                       
            
        }
```

when i try to post to request it gives me following error

**A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:)**

i think it gives error due to : in CreatedON field ( for time part).

is the post values are also sent through URL to ServiceStack URL ? if yes

**1) what if we have very large and complex requestDTO resulting into large number of characters (greater than allowed )in URL?**

**2) how to make above scenario work as ":" is reserved and cant be sent through URL?**

**3) How to see request URL Generated from client ?**

My Client code in MVC.net is

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["applicationUrl"])
                {
                    //for windows authentication
                    Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials      

                };

 var result = client.Post (new ReportDemo 
                 {
                     UserName = model.UserName,
                     EmployerID = model.EmployerID,
                     Report = model.Report,
                     selectedDataList =userReportViewModel.selectedDataList 

                 });
```

Thanks in advance,
Amol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the `/path/info` of the Url should be specified in the `[Route]`. Ideally routes should use a human-readable logically-structured Url that refers to a "Resource" (noun). See the [SeviceStack REST Events Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15235822/85785) for different examples.

Routes should also **never include complex types** and any variable that isn't on the `[Route]` is automatically sent in the HTTP Request Body for `POST` requests or the QueryString from `GET` Requests.

For a User Report like this I would choose a URL that identifies the report, if the report has a name like "Demo Report" I would use a path info like:

```
[Route("/reports/demo")] 
public class ReportDemo : IReturn<String> { ... }
```

Otherwise if this is a Report for Users you may instead want to use something like:

```
[Route("/users/{UserName}/reports/demo")] 
public class ReportDemo : IReturn<String> { ... }
```

You can check what url is used by using the [Reverse Routing](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Routing#reverse-routing) Extension methods, e.g:

```
var request = ReportDemo { UserName = "Foo", ... };

request.ToPostUrl().Print(); //= /users/Foo/reports/demo
```

Now you can send your Request with any property not in the Route getting POST'ed to the above url, e.g:

```
string result = client.Post (new ReportDemo {
     UserName = userReportViewModel.UserName,
     EmployerID = userReportViewModel.EmployerID,
     Report = userReportViewModel.Report,
     selectedDataList =userReportViewModel.selectedDataList 
 });
```

If your Report does return a `string` you can use `IReturn<string>` however if it returns a Response DTO you'll want to use that instead, e.g `IReturn<ReportDemoResponse>`.