# servicestack - make request dto parameters REQUIRED

Tags: servicestack

I have a request DTO like so:

```
[Route("/appusers/resetpwd/{UserId}", "PUT")]
public class ResetPassword : IReturn<AppUserDto>
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public string OldPassword { get; set; }
    public string NewPassword { get; set; }

    public ResetPassword(Guid userId, string oldPassword, string newPassword)
    {
        UserId = userId;
        OldPassword = oldPassword;
        NewPassword = newPassword;
    }
}
```

The metadata page shows the three properties as REQUIRED = No in the list. Can they be made required? Or does this simply mean I have to check them on the server and throw an exception as is explained in the [wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/New-API#structured-error-handling)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare required fields using [ServiceStack's built-in ValidationFeature](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Validation#validation-feature), e.g:

Enable in AppHost with:

```
Plugins.Add(new ValidationFeature());

//Register All Validators in Assembly
container.RegisterValidators(typeof(MyValidator).Assembly);
```

Configure with:

```
public class ResetPasswordValidator : AbstractValidator<ResetPassword>
{
    public ResetPasswordValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.UserId).NotEmpty();
        RuleFor(x => x.OldPassword).NotEmpty();
        RuleFor(x => x.NewPassword).NotEmpty();
    }
}
```

#### [Designing Message-based and HTTP APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39950289/85785)

Note some serializers require all DTO's to have a parameterless constructor. Also Resetting a Users Password isn't a valid `PUT` Operation which is expected to be idempotent and roughly translates to "PUT this resource at this location", it's more appropriately sent as a POST.

You can find some tips on designing message-based and HTTP APIs in ServiceStack in this [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39950289/85785) where I would rewrite this Request DTO as:

```
[Route("/users/{UserId}/reset-password", "POST")]
public class ResetPassword : IReturn<ResetPasswordResponse>
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public string OldPassword { get; set; }
    public string NewPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Although if this Service doesn't need to return a response it can also just return void, e.g:

```
public class ResetPassword : IReturnVoid { ... }
```

And implemented in your Service with:

```
public void Any(ResetPassword request) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks Demis, helpful tips like always. Just reading [this book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920021575.do) about REST API Design rules. It is a bit old but helps. Yes I added Validators yesterday (using Jeremy's FluentValidator already for quite some time) and I am just implementing a `NotEmptyGuidValidator` custom validator for the above use case. Just one thing: I had problems with async/await when using IReturnVoid with something like cannot convert void to Task or so... (Sorry don't remember the exact error) If I see this again, I post a new message.

Comment: @ThommyB Were you using the `SendOneWay()` Service Client API?

Comment: I don't think so, I guess it was a `PutAsync()`, but I can't currently find it. But I think I will get to this again and then I will post a new question here.