# what is the best way to do versioning in service stack microservices

Tags: asp.net-core, servicestack, versioning, microservices

I am using service stack with .net core, the service stack docs [here](http://docs.servicestack.net/versioning) say to implement IHasVersion but how we can route request coming for two different versions. Does that mean we need to have two different instances for the same service?

Answer (score 1):

ServiceStacks recommendation is [evolve Services gracefully and not try to maintain multiple implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400071/servicestack-restful-resource-versioning/12413091#12413091) which causes undue friction in static type language.