# Servicestack SendAll is working but sending an error

Tags: c#, servicestack

I am sending a CSV and de-serializing it.

```
 List<CompanyService> responseX;
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(files[0].InputStream))
            {
                // convert stream to string
                string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
                List<InsertCompany> deserializeFromString = ServiceStack.Text.CsvSerializer.DeserializeFromString<List<InsertCompany>>(text);
                responseX = Gateway.SendAll<CompanyService>(deserializeFromString);
            }


 /// <summary>
        /// To insert the company
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public long Post(InsertCompany request)
        {
            var company = request.ConvertTo<Company>();
            company.AuditId = UserAuth.Id;
            var result = Db.Insert<Company>(company, selectIdentity: true);

            //History
            CreateCompanyHistory(result, "INSERT", UserAuth.Id);

            //See the SQL that was generated
            //var lastSql = Db.GetLastSql();
            return result;
        }
```

When I call Sendall it calls the CompanyService and proesses all the List then sends back an error. but the records get saved in the database. error= `System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: 'Type definitions should start with a '{', expecting serialized type 'CompanyService', got string starting with: 71'`

On a side note, I cannot find any documentation for the  ServiceStack.Text.CsvSerializer.DeserializeFromString

Edit--

My CSV for Clarity

```
CompanyName,ParentCompanyId,City,Country,Email,Phone,Address1,Address2,Latitude,Longitude
Sub Company 8A,8,,,a@c.n,,dfg,,0,0
Sub Company 8B,8,,,W@RF.COM,7777,f,,0,0
Sub Company 8C,8,,,a@c.com,7777,d,,0,0
Sub Company 8D,8,,,abc@gmail.com,7777,2,,0,0
Sub Company 8E,8,,,abc@gmail.com,7777,2,,0,0
Sub Company 8F,8,,,abc@gmail.com,7777,2,,0,0
```

-edit 2

These were the first APIs i wrote using ST. I forgot to modify them to use a correct return type.  This is what I have been using and switching to it resolved the error.

```
public class ResponseList : IResponseItemList
{
    public List<dynamic> Result { get; set; }
}

public interface IResponseItemList
{
    List<dynamic> Result { get; set; }
}

public class Response : IResponseItem
{
    public dynamic Result { get; set; }
}

public interface IResponseItem
{
    dynamic Result { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Exactly which line throws the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that the CSV is not in the format `CsvSerializer` expects, e.g. you would get this error when trying to deserialize JSON in CSV.

The only text that the `CsvSerializer.Deserialize*` APIs should be deserializing is CSV that was originally serialized with `CsvSerializer`. It should be able to deserialize simple generic CSV files, but the moment you have any complex Types (which CSV doesn't support) it expects the opinionated output generated by `CsvSerializer`.

Comment: The serializer seems to be working fine. It's erroring after it calls SendAll and after all the loops happen to call the Insert records. It's failing on the return. I added my csv if it helps.

Comment: @SteveColeman ok your Services [should not return value types only reference Types](https://docs.servicestack.net/service-return-types#services-should-only-return-reference-types). The return Type should be whatever `IReturn<TResponse>` type your `InsertCompany` Request DTO is implementing which should be a reference type like a Response DTO, or can be a `string`. If you want to return `void` have your Service implement `IReturnVoid` that you can call from your gateway with `PublishAll()`.

Comment: I posted what I used to resolve it. Seems to work fine. Do you see any issue with dynamic types?

Comment: @SteveColeman Yes it will fail in a lot of serializers and different languages and unknown types like `object` has [imposed security restrictions](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text#late-bound-object-and-interface-runtime-types). Use a string if you want to hold an arbitrary types, or my recommendation is to [use explicit Request DTOs](https://docs.servicestack.net/why-remote-services-use-dtos) as it forms part of your Service Contract which will let you [version Services gracefully](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12413091/85785) without breaking existing clients.

Comment: @SteveColeman You can also use a Generic Response Types, `dynamic` is likely going to cause you runtime interoperability issues in future.

Comment: Thanks Demis, Appreciate the responses.